# imap not working in vim with sshrc

Tags: vim, ssh, key-bindings

I am using this really cool GitHub project: [sshrc](https://github.com/Russell91/sshrc) to bring my vimrc  around when I connect to my servers through SSH. Everything is working fine excepted `imap` bindings. Here the line which causes the problem.

```
imap <special> ts <esc>
```

And so I noticed that every `imap` key does not work. I have tried for instance to empty my vimrc and to add only.

```
imap aa xyz
```

But not working neither.

Here is the return of `:imap`.

```
i  ts            <Esc>
```

And finally, here is the content of my `.sshrc`.

```
export VIMINIT="let \$MYVIMRC='$SSHHOME/.sshrc.d/.vimrc' | source \$MYVIMRC"
```

It is maybe due to sshrc and not directly vim but I can't figure out how to debug it.

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Here is the `verbose imap` command.

```
i  ts            <Esc>
    Last set from /tmp/.myuser.sshrc.oOAh/.sshrc.d/.vimrc
```

This file is the uploaded file by sshrc and referenced into the `.sshrc`.

Comment: What is the output of `:verbose imap` in command line?

Comment: Your plugin or system defaults may override your mappings. Try putting `:au BufEnter *.* :imapclear` and then `:au BufEnter *.* :imap as xyz` in vimrc file. It might work.

Comment: I've added the result of the command `:verbose imap` into the post. It is not working even with your manipulation. I still have `i  as            xyz` from `:imap` but nothing happens in edit mode when I type `as`.

Comment: It may have problem with timeout related options. Did you typed 'as' sooner as possible? What is the output of `:set timeout`?

Comment: `:set timeout` does not output anything. But I tried to type it as fast as possible. Not working. And that is weird because even if I try `:imap b xyz` with a single key, it does not work.

Comment: It work for me! Did you tried in your own vim, without sshrc file? Getting the same problem again?

Comment: Yes, it is working with my own vim. The problem occurs just when I am using it with sshrc... But this tool is only uploading a `.vimrc` file remotely in a temporary folder and then changing the `VIMINIT` environment variable. So I can't see the problem...